Is using SetWindowText the best way to append text to a Win32 Edit control?
I'm creating a CLI-like tool using the Win32 API, which I need for a personal project,  but the method I use seems to be inefficient:
HWND wnd = CreateWindowEx(0, className, temp, WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_CAPTION|WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEAFULT, 500, 700, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);
HWND hConsole = CreateWindow(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER|WS_VSCROLL|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 10, 60, 470, 590, wnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

...

void addData(std::string newData){

    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hConsole);
    std::wstring consoleText(length,L'\0');
    GetWindowText(hConsole,&consoleText[0],length+1);
    std::string consoleStr = ConvertWideCahrToString(consoleText.c_str());
    consoleStr += newData;
    consoleStr += "\r\n";

    std::wstring updatedConsoleText(consoleStr.begin(),consoleStr.end());

    SetWindowText(hConsole, updatedConsoleText.c_str());
}

This seems like creating two copies of a large amount of text, as in the above function we need to first extract all the text from the window and then append the newData to the extracted data and then display it again.
The reason I am trying to find a better way is that the number of these types of CLI I want to create will be 8-10 and the amount of data that will be displayed will be high and fragmented, so this function will be called many times. So, whenever I need to append even a small amount of data, this will need to extract all the data and then append the newData.
Is there a better way to perform this task? Like having an output stream which just appends the text?
I did think of having a string on the stack, so whenever I need to append any newData I just append it to this string and display this string, so there will be one less task of extracting data before displaying.
Another method I thought of was to store it in a file and read the file. But this doesn't seem feasible as I will have to read the entire file and store it to display the text.

maybe unrelated but Create window(L'Edit',L'', ...) is wrong

With Edit control, you can use EM_REPLACESEL message to insert/update a fragment of text.

Depending on your needs, you might consider a list box control instead of an edit control.  It's easy to append lines to a list box, which makes it pretty good if all you need is a scrollable list of lines of text.  But if you need user interaction more similar to a text editor (like wrapping of long lines, selecting substrings, etc.), you're better off with an edit control and the good advice here.

Remy's answer is completely right. Please accept it if you check it is what you need.

You are reading the window text as a std::wstring, then converting it to a std::string (which is a lossy conversion), just to convert it back to a std::wstring (which you are doing incorrectly). That in itself is inefficient when you could just use the original std::wstring as-is.
If you can change your addData() function to take a std::wstring instead, then the code you showed can be simplified to the following:
void addData(const std::wstring &newData){

    std::wstring consoleText(length, L'\0');

    // resize in case GetWindowTextW() returns smaller text than expected...
    consoleText.resize(GetWindowTextW(hConsole, &consoleText[0], length + 1));

    std::wstring updatedConsoleText = consoleText + newData + L"\r\n";
    SetWindowTextW(hConsole, updatedConsoleText.c_str());
}

If you are worried about any potential allocation overhead due to concatenating large strings, then you can preallocate the full memory up front, eg:
void addData(const std::wstring &newData){

    int length = GetWindowTextLengthW(hConsole);

    std::wstring consoleText;
    consoleText.reserve(length + newData.size() + 2);

    // resize() will adjust only the size as long as it's smaller than the capacity...
    consoleText.resize(length);
    consoleText.resize(GetWindowTextW(hConsole, &consoleText[0], length + 1));

    // these will fill the existing capacity...
    consoleText += newData;
    consoleText += L"\r\n";

    SetWindowTextW(hConsole, consoleText.c_str());
}

If changing the newData parameter to a std::wstring is not an option for you, then at least consider converting newData to wchar_t locally, instead of converting consoleText to std::string, eg:
void addData(const std::string &newData){

    int textLength = GetWindowTextLengthW(hConsole);
    int newDataLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, newData.c_str(), newData.size(), nullptr, 0);

    std::wstring consoleText(textLength + newDataLength + 2, L'\0');

    textLength = GetWindowTextW(hConsole, &consoleText[0], textLength + 1);

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, newData.c_str(), newData.size(), &consoleText[textLength], newDataLength);
    textLength += newDataLength;

    std::copy_n(L"\r\n", 2, consoleText.begin() + textLength);
    textLength += 2;

    consoleText.resize(textLength);

    SetWindowTextW(hConsole, consoleText.c_str());
}

If you absolutely need the consoleText to be a std::string then you should use the ANSI version of the Win32 API instead and let the OS handle the conversions for you, eg:
void addData(const std::string& newData){

    int length = GetWindowTextLengthA(hConsole);

    std::string consoleText;
    consoleText.reserve(length + newData.size() + 2, '\0');

    consoleText.resize(length);
    consoleText.resize(GetWindowTextA(hConsole, &consoleText[0], length + 1));

    consoleText += newData;
    consoleText += "\r\n";

    SetWindowTextA(hConsole, consoleText.c_str());
}


Now, that being said, as @IgorTandetnik mentioned in this comment, there is a MUCH simpler way to append data to the end of an EDIT control - you can use the EM_REPLACESEL message.  Simply position the control's caret at the very end of the existing text, with the selection set to a length of 0, and then "replace" the selection.  The new text will be inserted at the caret position.  So, you won't need to retrieve the existing text at all, so no need to perform unnecessary memory allocations:
void appendTextToConsole(LPCWSTR text) {
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hConsole);
    SendMessage(hConsole, EM_SETSEL, length, length);
    SendMessage(hConsole, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(text));
}

void addData(const std::wstring &newData){
    //appendTextToConsole((newData + L"\r\n").c_str());
    appendTextToConsole(newData.c_str());
    appendTextToConsole(L"\r\n");
}

